# UIButton label disappears if view is being presented after URLSession

Tags: swift

I am making a social application which is checking whether the user's logged in or not via URLSession.

So I created 3 ViewControllers

1. CustomLaunchScreenVC
2. LoginVC
3. MainVc

***CustomLaunchScreenVC***:

After view did appear, I call the **checkIfSignedIn()** function, that checks if there are saved session values in the user defaults.

If *NOT*, it loads the ***LoginVC***

If *YES* it calls another function: **loginWithSession(uid, session)**

This function (loginWithSession) may be delayed due to the fact that there is an URLRequest inside it.

It checks on the website if session is valid then either calls the goToMainVC() or goToLoginVC() function

---

Now the problem is, that if there is a saved session, but it is not valid, then the app should go to the SignInVC, and it does, but the buttons' labels on this VC disappear and I have no clue why.

(I tried something, and after removing the **URLSession Task** from the **loginWithSession()** function, the problem solved and buttons are fine. But I really need that URLSession function..)

So maybe it is because there is some delay due to the internet connection and after that presenting a VC causes problems like that.

And here is the code for CustomLaunchScreenVC (simplified):

```
class CustomLaunchScreenVC : UIViewController {


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        checkIfSignedIn()
    }

    func checkIfSignedIn(){
        let uid = defaults.integer(forKey: "uid")
        let session = defaults.string(forKey: "session")
        if uid != nil && session != nil {
            loginWithSession(session: session, uid: uid) { response in
                if let response = response {

                    if (response!.loggedIn == "yes"){
                        self.goToMainVC()
                    } else {
                        self.goToLoginVC() // This does NOT work, UIButtons' labels are NOT loading, and I don't know why :(
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // there is no saved session so user is not logged in
            self.goToLoginVC() // This does works, UIButtons' labels are loading
        }
    }




    func loginWithSession(session: String, uid: Int, completion: @escaping (CustomTypeArray??)->()){

        let connectUrl = URL(string: "http://website.com/common/php/sessionLogin.php")
        var request = URLRequest(url: connectUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userId=\(uid)&session=\(session)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            //Simplified the code
            if (data.loggedin == "yes"){
                return completion(CustomTypeArray(loggedIn : "yes"))
            } else {
                return completion(CustomTypeArray(loggedIn : "no"))
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }



    func goToLoginVC(){
        let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
        self.present(loginVC, animated: false)
    }
    func goToMainVC(){
        let mainVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC
        self.present(mainVC, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Video of the problem: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DQf3fSoo_Q&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Al UI code must be on the main queue.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem! Thank you @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rmaddy helped me, thank you!

The solution is to move all the UI code to the main queue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
    self.goToSigninVC()
})
```